# Manage the heights of two panels dynamically using directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, panel, directive

There are two panels in html page, set with the min-height.I want to equate the heights of two panels dynamically based on the height of highest panel using directive.I have worked with the following directive,

```
app.directive('setHeightmaster', function ($timeout) {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(function () {

            element.css("min-height", $('#mp').css("height"));

        });
   });

app.directive('setHeightpanel', function ($timeout) {


return function (scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch(function () {
        element.css("min-height", $('#hm').css("height"));

    });

}
```

});

In html file, I have included the directive for two panels section.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pad-left-3 pad-right-1">
    <section class="panel panel-success sideMealPanel" id="hm" set-heightmaster>
                <div class="panel-heading panel-title">
            <span>Meal
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body panel-body-height-without-footer pad-0">
            <div class="pad-15" ng-include="'..MealtimeDetail.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 pad-left-1 pad-right-0 page-table">
    <section class="panel panel-success" id="mp" set-heightpanel>
</div>
```

When the height of one panel changes, other panel's height should be dynamically set to the height of first panel and vice a versa. The above code equates the heights of two panels leaving the blank space at the bottom of content in both panels. I want to remove that extra space and eauate the heights without leaving the space in both panels at the bottom. 
Where am i wrong with above code? How can i solve this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do this in this way.
Your directive would only be executed only once or the first time content is loaded. So, when your content has changed, there is no way for the directive to know that it has to work its magic again.

You need to make sure that code runs again after content is loaded again.
After you content has changed, broadcast an event from the controller, and catch it in the directive and then re-adjust the heights.

Watch doesn't works over CSS properties.
And Event mechanism works much better.